# Algorithm to hide box on blur

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dom

I have code to attach a floating control to all text boxes in a form. I've composed [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g96nr/) to show it but code is basically this:

```css
#box{
    position: absolute;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```js
var $box = $('<div id="box"><input type="button" value="Click Me"></div>').hide().appendTo("#main-form");
$("#main-form").on("focus", ":text, textarea", function(){
    $text = $(this);
    $box.show().position({
        my: "right top",
        at: "left top",
        of: $text
    });
});
```

When user enters a textarea (either with mouse or keyboard) the control box pops up beside the textarea. So far so good.

My problem is that I cannot figure out a good algorithm to *hide* the box when it's no longer necessary (i.e., the user has moved away from the textarea). The obvious approach is not adequate:

```
$("#main-form").on("blur", ":text, textarea", function(){
    $box.hide();
});
```

... because it doesn't allow to *use* the control box—it hides as soon as the user tries to click the button.

I'm currently trying something on this line:

```
$("#main-form").on("blur", ":text, textarea", function(){
    if( $box.is(":focus") ){ // :-?
        $box.hide();
    }
});
```

... but I can't manage to detect whether focus has moved to the control box or not. Any idea?

**Edit:** The [jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/focus-selector/) says this:

> If you are looking for the currently focused element, `$(
>   document.activeElement )` will retrieve it without having to search
>   the whole DOM tree.

... but [in my tests](http://jsfiddle.net/YpEdD/) it's **always** the `<body>` node :-?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achive this behaviour by listening blur like you are doing + click event on document:

```
// Hide the $box if clicked anywhere outside of it
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    if (!$box.data('over')) {
        $box.hide();
    } 
});

// Set a flag if $box is currently hovered
$box.on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $(this).data('over', true);
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $(this).data('over', false);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g96nr/1/

Comment: Awesome. You've absolutely worked out all the details. Though my full code is more complex (it has animations and the box actually does things) I've been able to adapt your code without any problem. Thank you very much.